# How do you set the background color of an object (represented by data template) in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

How do I change the background color of an object (referred to by its observablecollection index) in c# ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < numTapeSlots; i++)
        {
            if (t.tapeLocation == mainTapes[i].tapeLocation)
            {
                mainTapes[i] = t;
                mainTapes[i].Background = "light red";
            }
        }
```

Only changes a particular object if it meets the criteria.

Comment: What were you expecting? Duh.

Comment: Did you try changing that last statement to mainTapes[i].Background = Colors.Red;?  I'm assuming the rest of your code is OK but there's really not enough information to be sure.  Regardless, I'd be surprised if your snippet even compiled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any class that inherits from the [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Control.aspx) class has the `Background` property, which is a type of [`Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.aspx)... basically, you can only assign a `Brush` object to it. If you want the brush to be a solid color, you can use the [`SolidColorBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx).

In you're case, you're going to want to do:

```
mainTapes[i].Background = new SolidColorBrush(...);
```

Now, since the `Colors` static class does not contain a static property for "Light Red", you can always just use methods such as [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb.aspx), [`Color.FromRgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb.aspx), etc. For example:

```
mainTapes[i].Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255,100,100));
```

I could go on and on about how to create the appropriate color, but you get the point...

Comment: Thank you.  I was really unsure of the whole brush idea and I have never used an observable collection before.